# Ownership Issue with wordpress group and user Server and SFTP

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, apache2, sftp

First off, thanks to all of you being so supportive in this Forum. I came here to resolve many problems already posted by the community. Today I am reaching out to you because I am noticing an odd behavior and unfortunatley, the solutions I found here are not working for me.

I am not sure what Linux version I have so I will post the Serverdetails here:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
Static hostname: mx.###.###
Icon name: ###
Chassis: vm
Machine ID: ###
Boot ID: ###
Virtualization: kvm
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Kernel: Linux 5.10.0-22-amd64
Architecture: x86-64
```

I have a chown and writing issue with WordPress and STFP; conflicting ownership issues.

Every time I change the owner (`chown -R mark:www-owner directory/`) to write files via SFTP, WordPress looses the writing permissions. It then asks me to enter the FTP credentials every time I want to install something or update the WP instance.

I have a Sudo User, let's call him Mark. Mark is as well a Sudo user and a normal user, that I can change to sudo with the sudo -i command.

In my file system, the default ownership for all files and folders is set to `www-owner:www-owner`. I just set up the SFTP, so I could also easily upload some files to my server without the need to start the console and drop them on the server first. For that I had to change the writing permissions for the user Mark, so I could upload files to the SFTP. But then WP lost all the writing permissions

**This is the setup I tried:**

1. Default ownership: `www-owner:www-owner` (WordPress operates just fine
   with this)
   -> Problem here: I don't have writing permissions via SFTP with the user Mark.
2. I changed the ownership for folders and subfolders (chown -R) to `mark:www-owner`.
   -> Now I have writing permissions via SFTP with the user Mark, but WordPress cannot write anymore in the specified folder and the issues start piling up.
3. I added to both users www-owner and Mark to a Group called "wp-admin" and changed the ownership of the folders to `mark:wp-admin`. I have the same issue as in 2.

**Conclusion:**

4. If www-owner is both the owner and the group, WP works fine. But I have no permissions to upload or change files via SFTP with the user Mark.
5. If I change the ownership to `mark:www-owner`. WP cannot write files anymore.

I also tried adding both users to a new group called wp-admin and changed the ownership to `mark:wp-admin`. Same issue here, WP cannot write files.

**I want to achieve,** that both users can write in the directory as of wp-admin:wp-admin. But as I only have a group called wp-admin, I get the error that wp-admin user does not exist. So, I seem to be unable to add a group of as owners.

I am at the end of my vocabulary and I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.14. Please correct the question.

Comment: Thanks David, as I could not find the correct version, I added the kernel information of my server. Does that help?``